# Event listeners in browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

gotta question about event listeners in different browsers. First i got this in chrome in function: `event.preventDefault();`. Works as charming but not in Firefox. I have tried different approaches like `myFunction(event)` or `event = event || window.event;` in the event. Also probed what FF does with `window` element and preventing is not one of them.

So i generate html with jquery for google maps api:

```
data = '<a href="#" class="copyLink">Click or right click to copy and share</a>';
```

and data is processed afterwise

```
 infowindow.setContent(data);
```

But it wont work, `event.preventDefault()` is never called in this method:

```
function copylink(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
...........
```

Comment: What exactly is it that is not working? `event.preventDefault`? Calling the `copyLink()` function?

Comment: Preventing FirexFox for handling events when something is clicked. Here it would be event.preventDefault

Comment: I don't think the function is being called to run `preventDefault()`. why not just add a inline event attribute. `<a href="#" class="copyLink" onclick="copylink();">`

Comment: Here is simple jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/24bx8khv/3/ Basicaly FF ingores event.preventdefault(); and opens link.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Chrome and in Firefox:
https://jsfiddle.net/24bx8khv/11/

```
<a href="https://www.neti.ee" class="copylink">Copy link</a>

$('.copylink').click(function(event) {
event = event || window.event;
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('foo');
});
```